# trigger action on active class

Tags: jquery, triggers, slide

I made a slider and captions, descriptions for each slide. I'd like to use jquery to animate the captions, when slide is active. Somehow I managed to do that but it's not like I think it should be done ;) here is the code i made, it works but on timers, could anyone help me to trigger this ?

```
$(function () {
    var $anchors = $('.description');
    (function _loop(idx) {
        $anchors.removeClass('highlight').eq(idx).addClass('highlight');
        setTimeout(function () {
            _loop((idx + 1) % $anchors.length);
        }, 7000);
        $('.description').fadeIn(2000);
    }(0));
});

window.setInterval(function () {        
    if ($('#test2.highlight')) {            
        $('.description').removeAttr('style');
        $('.description').fadeIn(2000);
    }
}, 7000); // checks all 800ms
```

html

```
 <ul class="slides">

    <li id="test" class="" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; height: 460px; display: list-item; opacity: 0.42695848571879425;">

   <a href="http://tyf">

     <span id="test3" class="caption highlight" style="top: 63.088278221567435px;">test2</span>                             


                                                </a>
                        <img src="http://hurompolska.pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/przepisy_tlo.png" width="100%">                                                       <span id="test2" class="description highlight" style="display: inline; opacity: 0.24278023310924668;">opis2</span>                          </li>
                                        <li id="test" class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; height: 460px; display: list-item; opacity: 0.5730415142812058;">

                                                <a href="http://bum">

                                                     <span id="test3" class="caption" style="top: 63.088278221567435px;">test</span>                            


                                                </a>
                        <img src="http://hurompolska.pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/top1.jpg" width="100%">                                                       <span id="test2" class="description" style="display: inline; opacity: 0.24278023310924668;">tesfasd</span>                          </li>

            </ul>
```

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: will it be good if i show u website ? i dont know how to use fiddle , never done that yet xd

www.hurompolska.pl